# Menu items in main menu bar show up with different font sizes.. what gives?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I just noticed the strangest thing when updating one of my Mac applications.

The menu bar of the application when run has different font sizes (!?). Some items are in the normal system text size (13 point?) and others are a few points smaller (11 points?). What gives?

I didn't even know that you could do this.. never mind understanding how this just came about of its own volition..

I immediately zeroed in on the likely culprit XCode 4, but compiling the same project with 3.2.5 shows the same problem.

I'm rather flummoxed by this.. has anybody come across this weird phenomenon?

Best regards,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

I`m used to iOS but you may have a similar issue. The UILabels have an "autoshrink" property, which reduces the font size if the text is too long, to avoid truncating it. You can turn this property off in the Interface Builder. Hope this helps!